# What's the URL of the video showing an EA representative talking about game programming?

Tags: software-engineering, game-industry, video

The video shows an EA representative talking about how a programmer can get into the industry by showing some demos (in fact, he shows a physics demo presented by a candidate who wanted a job at EA). The demo shown depicts kind of a ragtime doll made of yellow cobblestones.

I don't remember if I watched on YouTube or Vimeo and I frankly cannot find it after a few hours of work. I just remember the fact that it was taken at a GDC or a SIGGRAPH convention.

Thanks in advance. I'm really frustrated because I'd love to show this video to some fellow developers (coders).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if the exact video you're looking for is included in this collection, but the link below includes 23 different lectures by EA employees on various aspects of game development:

[Electronic Arts: Game Development Lectures](http://academicearth.org/courses/electronic-arts-game-development)

If nothing else, at least hopefully you can find something interesting and worthwhile in one of those videos.  Good luck!